# Binding to both a view model and source entity in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am making use of the DataGrid component provided as part of the UI Community Toolkit and would like to have a couple of cells that show a dropdown (ComboBox).

The ItemsSource for the dropdown should come from the view model, while the SelectedItem should bind to the context of the current item (row).

```xml
<tc:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding GridItems}">
  <tc:DataGrid.Columns>
    <tc:DataGridTemplateColumn Tag="ExampleColumn" Header="Example Column">
      <tc:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding <ViewModelProperty>}" SelectedItem="{Binding <ContextProperty>}" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </tc:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </tc:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    ...
  </tc:DataGrid.Columns>
</tc:DataGrid>
```

How can I configure the bindings for the ComboBox so that the `ItemsSource` is pulled from the view model of the page, while the `SelectedItem` binds to the current item in the `GridItems` collection.

Most articles talk about using RelativeSource and AncestorType but I don't believe these are available in UWP applications.

Comment: Have you solved your issue? Do you have other questions?

Answer (score 0):

> > How can I configure the bindings for the ComboBox so that the ItemsSource is pulled from the view model of the page, while the SelectedItem binds to the current item in the GridItems collection.

The DataContext of ComboBox is the current item(e.g Model) in the GridItems collection, if you want to bind SelectedItem with the current item in the GridItems collection, just bind the property from the current item with the SelectedItem. And for ItemsSource, if you want to bind with the view model of the page, you can subscribe the **Loading** event of ComboBox and then set the lists from view model of the page to ItemsSource  in this event.  For example:

.xaml:

```
<tc:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding GridItems}">
    <tc:DataGrid.Columns>
        <tc:DataGridTemplateColumn Tag="ExampleColumn" Header="Example Column">
            <tc:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Model">
                    <ComboBox Loading="ComboBox_Loading" SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItemFromModel}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </tc:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </tc:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </tc:DataGrid.Columns>
</tc:DataGrid>
```

.cs:

```
private void ComboBox_Loading(FrameworkElement sender, object args)
{
    ComboBox box = sender as ComboBox;
    box.ItemsSource = ViewModelFromPage.Lists;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to fill the _ComboBox_ items using _ItemsSource_ binding (instead of _Loading_ event approach)?